# Child to Parent Component Communication in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-seed

I'm using https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed for my project. I need to update value in shopping cart via `header` component while clicking `addtocart` in my `item` component. Please help me. I'm new to Angular 2. I used the same code structure as in https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Please add some code, what you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular services to communicate between components, directives and services. You can also use @Input and @Output to communicate between parent child components. There is other ways, depending on your needs...Check the angular page:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score -1):

Define the property in services with type of subject (observable) and invoked or used that property in child component, use the next function and pass the data in next function. In parent component just subscribe this observable. following https://github.com/aryanisml/Angular-Services-Observables  will help you.